# knitting rmarkdown throws error printing result of contour()

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to knit the following code into an html document. The code runs fine in Rstudio but fails when I attempt to knit - what am I missing here?

```
library(e1071)

load(url("http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/ESL.mixture.rda"))
names(ESL.mixture)
attach(ESL.mixture)

plot(x,col=y+2,pch=c(17,19)[y+1],xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2]),cex=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,cex.lab=1.5)

data <- data.frame(x, as.factor(y) )
colnames(data) <- c("x1", "x2", "y1")
attach(data)

svmfit <- svm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = data, kernel = "radial", cost = 32.1, gamma = 0.5, scale = FALSE)

xgrid <- expand.grid(x1=px1,x2= px2)
ygrid <- predict(svmfit,xgrid)

plot(x,col=y+2,pch=c(17,19)[y+1],xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2]),cex=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,cex.lab=1.5)

points(xgrid,col=as.numeric(ygrid)+1,pch=20,cex=.2)
contour(px1,px2,matrix(ygrid,69,99),level=1,add=TRUE)
```

This produced the following plot as desired.

[image: contour plot]

When attempting to knit it into a html report, it throws the following error. The dimensions of the data are definitely correct and those specified in the contour() call look fine as well, so am unclear on how to solve this.

```
Error in contour.default(px1, px2, matrix(ygrid, 69, 99), level = 1, add = TRUE) : 
  dimension mismatch
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> contour -> contour.default
```

Comment: Does the markdown include loading any packages? As it stands that gives me an error finding function `svm`

Comment: Apologies, it needs the e1071 package. I can't seem to edit the questions anymore.

Comment: With the addition of the `library` call that seems to knit fine for me - I'm struggling to reproduce your problem

Comment: Hi, this now works for me as well. Updating knitr and rmarkdown solved the issue. Thanks a lot for attempting to reproduce the error.